# Protractor: there is an error but the test is passed

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, protractor

I'm creating a test tool using protractor and other library like chai, cucumber and gherkin. I have three files:

1. my_feature.feature - used to specify gherkin features
2. test_step.js - this file contains the step definitions
3. index.html - is the web page I'm testing

**my_feature.feature**

```
# features/my_feature.feature

Feature: Test cucumber automation
  As a front-end developer
  I want to automate e2e testing

  
  Scenario: Altro test
    Given I go on "file:///Users/Emanuele/Desktop/lavoro/test-automation/app/html/index.html"
    Then The text of the element with selector "#test-button" should be "My button"
```

**test_step.js**

```
    'use strict';

var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var expect = chai.expect;

// Protractor won't wait for Angular
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

module.exports = function() {
  
  this.World = require('../support/world').World;

  // default timeout for all step definitions
  this.setDefaultTimeout(20 * 1000);

  /*
  ** Open a page based on an absolute url
  ** Ex. https://www.google.com
  */
  this.Given(/^I go on "([^"]*)"$/, function(url, callback){
    browser.get(url);

    callback();
  });

  /*
  ** Check if the text of the element with a given selector is equal to myText.
  */
  this.Then(/^The text of the element with selector "([^"]*)" should be "([^"]*)"$/, function(elementSelector, myText, callback){
    var selectedElement = element(by.css(elementSelector));

    //Resolve the promise
    selectedElement.getText().then(function(text){
      expect(text).to.equal(myText);
    });
    

    callback();
  });
};
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <button id="test-button">Test button</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I run the test I get a weird result because the two steps for the given scenario are both passed but I have an error in the second one due to `expect(text).to.equal(myText);` line.
This happens because, according with the gherkin feature, the text inside the button should be **My button** and not **Test button**.

Here you can find the result shown in my console:
[image]

I would like to know why the second step is passed even if there is an error? I think that the test should fail because the compared strings are different. Am I wrong? How can I avoid this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

If i resolve the promise using `eventually` from `chai-as-promised` I get the same result. All tests are passed but the error text is a little different:  `AssertionError: expected 'Test button' to equal 'My Button'`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two fixes for this problem.

**First:**

```
selectedElement.getText().then(function(text){
      try{
        expect(text).to.equal(myText); 
      } catch(error){
        callback(new Error("Compare error"));
      }
      callback(); 
});
```

Here I resolve the promise then I check if the text of the element is equal to the string `myText`. I don't like this solution even because, resolving the promise manually, I don't use a lot of feature of chai-as-promised.

**Second:**

```
expect(selectedElement.getText()).to.eventually.equal(myText).notify(callback);
```

I think this is the best solution and is based on [notify](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) provided by chai-as-promised.
This  [post](http://nicholasjackson.github.io/agile/bdd/angular/protractor/cucumber/protractor-cucumber/) about cucumber-protractor has been very helpful for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that because your assertion is in the callback of an asynchronous operation, the test completes before encountering the `expect(text).to.equal(myText);` statement and therefore passes.

You need to identify that the test shouldn't pass until the promise you're waiting on is resolved!

According to the [Chai documentation on promises](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised) the pattern I believe you should be using is:

```
expect(selectedElement.getText()).to.eventually.equal(myTest);
```

Comment: Same result. All tests are passed but in the end I got this error: AssertionError: expected 'Test button' to equal 'My Button'

Comment: Can you share your current source in a jsbin or jsfiddle?  I realize it won't be able to run necessarily but I'd like to see what changes you made.

Comment: Here you can find my github repo: https://github.com/Ema-jar/test-automation/tree/master/test/features

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You still have the assertion in the callback: https://github.com/Ema-jar/test-automation/blob/master/test/features/step_definitions/test.step.js#L114

Comment: I'm sorry, it's an older version with other stuff. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`getText()`, as a lot of other methods in `Protractor`, returns a *promise*,  use [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) and it's "eventually":

```
expect(selectedElement.getText()).to.eventually.equal(myText);
```

And, you clearly have `Test button` in the HTML, but you are expecting to see `My button` for some reason. In other words, should not it be:

```
Then The text of the element with selector "#test-button" should be "Test button"
```

Comment: Same result. All tests are passed but in the end I got this error: AssertionError: expected 'Test button' to equal 'My Button'